# How to color a table row without background color?

Tags: css, syncfusion

Are there any other CSS properties that can be used as an alternative for '*background-color*' to set the color of a <tr>?

I'm using a third-party tool that sets color of table elements via JavaScript. I cannot seem to override it using CSS , even with **! important**. The JavaScript code is also unavailable to me.

So I figured, setting the background color via an alternative method may work. But there's no property that I know that acts like background-color.

Any help will be great.

**PS**: I would prefer a CSS based solution rather than any form of script.

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS

Comment: use background to set background for the <tr> and show us what you have done

Comment: The code won't be much of a help. The issue is not with the property, and the background color will get set on the <tr>. But the third-party tool has a hover effect on tables that reset the colors when the mouse in hovered over it. There isn't anyway to over-ride that property with css.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this works for you:

```css
tr {
  background-color: red !important; // we want this to override
}
tr {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, blue) !important;
}
tr:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, green) !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: red !important;">
    <td>Table Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: background color will get set with the gradient. But when it is hovered, the color changes to it's stock color. This is the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer. When this not work, then it would be helpfully to know which way the hover state will alter the background-color.

Comment: Hi @AndyTschiersch, I already tried setting changes in the :hover state, long before I posted this question. It didn't work. It's like the hover implemented on the table is unalterable with the background property. I wish I had access to the javascript that changes the hover effect, but I don't have it, to give you more information.

Comment: But you can inspect the DOM with the devtools of your browser and so you can look what things changed during hover state.

Comment: This is not a Web App, but a desktop application. So there is no browser involved. However, I've used the DOM Explorer in Microsoft Visual Studio (where it was originally being developed) and still couldn't find the hover state changes. It showed no hover state changes of any sort and the background property isn't stricken out (appear to be overridden) either, which means, it's still a valid, existing css property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a very large inset `box-shadow`

```css
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* required */
}
td:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 200px green inset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: orange !important;">
    <td>Table Content</td>
    <td>Table Content</td>
    <td>Table Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: pink !important;">
    <td>Table Content</td>
    <td>Table Content</td>
    <td>Table Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```